# Sketches mechanics in link battles

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

What are the mechanics of the move sketch in link battles? I know in-game, it's essentially mimic but permanent. Is sketch permanent after the link battle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In link battles, [moves Sketched will remain until the end off the battle, but not afterward](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sketch_(move)#Effect).

> If the battle does not allow experience points to be earned (such as link battles or Battle Tower battles), any move learned via Sketch will be forgotten at the end of the battle.

I assume this means Sketch will remain on the Pokémon's Moveset after the battle completes.

Comment: So it's effectively Mimic in Link Battles (with less PP). Although I suppose Smeargle will retain the move on switch out, which is a bonus